# How to apply bold and bullet points?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, html-email

> The situation has caused many businesses and organizations to take continued preventive measures to protect their customers.
>
> - **Service:** Our teams are fully operational.
> - **Support:** We will do our best.

This is how I am trying to make it work.

`mymsg = mymsg & "<body style=""text-align: center; line-height: 1;"">" & "The situation has caused many businesses and organizations to take continued"`

```
<ul>
    <li> mymsg = mymsg & "<body style=""text-align: center; line-height: 1;"">" & "Service:</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.HTMLBody = "" _
          & "The situation has caused many business and organizations to take continued preventative measures to protect their customers." _
          & "<ul><li><b> Service: </b>Our teams are fully operational.</li>" _
          & "<li><b> Support: </b>We will do our best.</li><ul>"
```